# Could Windows Server 2008 Itanium come without Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, windows-server

We had the following question in our exam:

> Does Itanium-based windows server 2008, always come with Hyper-V feature?

Some students say yes and others say no. The guys who said no they found that in our slides (it's with hyper-v), and the guys who said yes they found an answer on a web page(it's without).

I said since it's a feature so I guess it can come without it then install it later, isn't it? Now we don't know the real answer beside we couldn't contact with our doctor for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

**Microsoft website -in Hardware requirements tag-, said:**

Hyper-V requires specific hardware. To install and use the Hyper-V role, you will need the following:
An x64-based processor. Hyper-V is available in 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008—specifically, the 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008 Standard, Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and Windows Server 2008 Datacenter. **Hyper-V is not available for 32-bit (x86) editions or Windows Server 2008 for Itanium-Based Systems.** However, the Hyper-V management tools are available for 32-bit editions. For more information about the tools, see Installing Hyper-V [Node].

Hardware-assisted virtualization. This is available in processors that include a virtualization option—specifically processors with Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel VT) or AMD Virtualization (AMD-V) technology.
Hardware-enforced Data Execution Prevention (DEP) must be available and enabled. Specifically, you must enable Intel XD bit (execute disable bit) or AMD NX bit (no execute bit).

You can identify systems that support the x64 architecture and Hyper-V by searching the Windows Server catalog for Hyper-V as an additional qualification (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=111228).

Comment: Sounds like itanium-based system doesn't come with Hyper-v  !! Thanx